# Running a language server in a Dockerfile: Binary file of the Language Server

Tags: docker, dockerfile, binaryfiles, xtext, languageservice

I built a simple language server following this tutorial:

http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/102_domainmodelwalkthrough.html

In this server, I have 5 folders,

```
org.example.domainmodel
org.example.domainmodel.ide
org.example.domainmodel.tests
org.example.domainmodel.ui
org.example.domainmodel.ui.tests
```

Now I need to run this language server inside a Docker image, and need the binary directory for it. Which binary directory out of the above 5 folders should I use? The actual language servers I've explored so far are quite different from what I've created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above project that I had created is used to develop Eclipse plugins. To create a LS to run in a Dockerfile, it is required to create a binary file (I used fatJar) from the Eclipse Xtext project that should be created as explained in [this tutorial](http://I%20have%20created%20a%20simple%20'Hello%20World'%20DSL%20using%20Xtext%20with%20the%20following%20grammar:%20-%20%20grammar%20org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl%20with%20org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals%20%20generate%20myDsl%20%22http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl%22%20%20Model:%20%20%20%20%20greetings+=Greeting*;%20%20Greeting:%20%20%20%20%20'Hello'%20name=ID%20'!';%20When%20I%20create%20it%20as%20an%20Eclipse%20plugin%20and%20run%20as%20an%20Eclipse%20Application,%20everything%20works%20fine;%20syntax%20highlighting,%20auto%20completion%20works%20fine.%20However,%20when%20I%20create%20it%20as%20a%20Gradle%20build%20with%20Fat%20Jar,%20and%20implement%20the%20Fat%20jar%20into%20Eclipse%20Che%20as%20a%20sidecar%20(by%20pushing%20a%20dockerfile%20with%20the%20fat%20jar%20embedded%20in%20it%20into%20Docker%20Hub),%20syntax%20highlighting%20does%20not%20work%20as%20expected.%20However,%20the%20editor%20understands%20the%20language.%20I%20know%20this%20because%20it%20provides%20auto-completion%20support%20and%20underlines%20in%20red%20when%20I%20type%20syntactically%20wrong%20statements.%20%20The%20statements%20do%20not%20have%20a%20colour%20variation%20at%20all.%20It%20looks%20like%20a%20simple%20.txt%20file.%20Is%20there%20a%20possible%20way%20to%20include%20syntax%20highlighting%20to%20my%20DSL%20when%20it%20is%20running%20in%20Eclipse%20Che?%20%20Thanks%20in%20advance!) (Should only complete up to 'Packaging the LS', inclusive). Note that when packaging the LS, it is enough to add the following code snippet in the *.ide project's build.gradle file : -

```
shadowJar {
    baseName = 'dsl-language-server'
    classifier = null
    version = null
}
```

Afterwards, the parent project should be built by `gradle shadowJar` command in the command prompt. Once it is done, a .jar file will be created in the following path: `*.ide/build/libs`

Then you'll need to create a separate directory and copy and paste the build folder into it, and create a file named `dockerfile` (no file extension) and include the following code in it: -

```
FROM barais/eclipse-xtend
ADD build/libs/dsl-language-server-ls.jar dsl-language-server-ls.jar
RUN sudo apt-get install socat
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y  software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y && \
    apt-get update && \
    echo oracle-java7-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections && \
    apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer && \
    apt-get clean
CMD socat TCP4-LISTEN:4417,reuseaddr,fork EXEC:"java -jar dsl-language-server-ls.jar"
```

Then build this file using Docker, and push it to your Docker Hub account as a repo. Use the following recipe to create a new stack in Eclipse Che to use the pushed repo from Docker Hub as a language server: -

```
services:
 dsl-language-server-ls:
  image : <youraccountname>/mydsl
  mem_limit : 1073741824
 dev-machine:
  image : eclipse/ubuntu_jdk8
  mem_limit : 2147483648
  depends_on:
   - dsl-language-server-ls
```

Edit the raw config and update it with the following code at the respective location in the config (Read the [che doc](https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/language-servers.html#ls-sidecars) for more information: -

```
"id": "mydsl-ls",
      "internal": "true",
      "type": "ls",
      "languageRegexes": "[ {\"languageId\":\"mydsllang\", \"regex\":\".*\\\\.mydsl$\"}]"
```

Create a file in a new project in Eclipse Che with the file extension you added (.mydsl) and the LS will start to run, allowing you to write code in your DSL.

Yay!